# python difference between the two form of matrix x[i,j] and x[i][j]

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i want to understand the difference between `x[i,j]` and `x[i][j]` where x is a matrix

```
x = np.zeros((N,M))
```

The answer that i found while doing the research is always about array with 2D dimension but in my case i have a matrix with two index to work with i and j and i need to manipulate the matrix according the index with a for loop.

```
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        for j in range(1,M+1):
            x[i-1][j-1]=random.uniform(5,10)
```

so can you help me understand the difference between `x[i,j]` and `x[i][j]`and to be more clear for each i(base station) there is a number of j (users)

Comment: Your `x` is a 2d array. `x[i, j]` is the preferred syntax.

Comment: Your use of a the word `matrix` is loose.  Is it just a 2d `ndarray`, or a `np.matrix`?  The difference matters.

Comment: Note you should use `x = np.random.uniform(5., 10., size=(N, M))`

Answer (score 3):

For simple indexing of a 2d array both forms work:

```
In [28]: x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [29]: x
Out[29]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [30]: x[1,2]
Out[30]: 5
In [31]: x[1][2]
Out[31]: 5
```

For `np.matrix` (which you probably shouldn't be using anyways) they aren't:

```
In [32]: X = np.matrix(x)
In [33]: X
Out[33]: 
matrix([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]])
In [34]: X[1,2]
Out[34]: 5
In [35]: X[1][2]
...
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

The two forms are not syntactically the same.  `[1][2]` first indexes with 1, and then indexes the result with 2.  That's not the same as indexing once with both parameters.

```
In [36]: x[1]
Out[36]: array([3, 4, 5])      # (3,) shape
In [37]: X[1]
Out[37]: matrix([[3, 4, 5]])   # (1,3) shape
```

The error arises because `np.matrix` returns another `np.matrix`.  So the next `[2]` indexing will again be indexing the first dimension.

`x[1]` is really short for `x[1,:]`, that is, index the first dimension, and slice all the rest  (or `X[1,...]` to allow for 3d and higher).  So `x[1][2]` is really

```
temp = x[1,:]
temp[2]
```

or for the matrix case:

```
temp = X[1,:]
temp[2,:]
```

In other words, it is 2 indexing operations.  It's a Python expression, not a specific `numpy` usage.

When we index with lists or slices, the difference between the two forms becomes more significant, especially when setting values.

I encourage beginners to use the `x[i,j]` form.  Don't use `x[1][2]` unless you really understand what is going on.

If needed I could get into how indexing is translated into calls to `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`.

Answer (score -3):

They are equivalent according to [Numpy v1.15.1 manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

> Note
> In Python, x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: The question is about `x[i][j]`, not `x[(i, j)]`