# Why does numpy not allow assignment of a doubly indexed numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to assign values of an array `arr_2` to a different array `arr_1`. However, I want to do this based on 2 selection criteria. As a working example, I define my selection criteria as such

```
import numpy as np

# An array of -1 values of shape(10,): [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
arr_1 = np.zeros(10, dtype=int) - 1
# An array of 0-9 values of shape(10,): [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
arr_2 = np.arange(10)

# Create an initial selection of values we want to change
# In this example: even indices: [ T F T F T F T F T F]
selection_a = np.arange(10) % 2 == 0

# Create a second selection based on selection_a: [F F F T T]
selection_b = arr_2[selection_a] > 5
```

Based on these two selection criteria I would like to assign the values of `arr_2` where both conditions hold to the array `arr_1`. I.e. equivalent to `[F F F F F F T F T F]`.

```
arr_1[selection_a][selection_b] = arr_2[selection_a][selection_b]
```

If I inspect both sides of the equation before the assignment, they yield the values that I expect:

```
print(arr_1[selection_a][selection_b]) # yields [-1 -1]
print(arr_2[selection_a][selection_b]) # yields [ 6, 8]
```

However, the assignment itself does not assign the values, i.e. `arr_1` remains unchanged. My question is, why is this the case?

**NB**: I know that in most (and maybe even all cases) this can be circumvented by creating a single criterion, however I want to know why using 2 separate criteria won't work.

If anything is unclear, please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

#### Edit

I investigated this a bit further and the problem seems to be in the left hand side of the equation as something like

```
arr_1[selection_a][selection_b] = 5
```

does not work either.

Comment: I'd do something like: `idx = arr_2[selection_a][selection_b]; arr_1[idx] = idx`

Comment: Define `selection_b` as `arr_2 > 5 & selection_a` then use `arr_1[selection_b] = 5`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta `selection_a` and `selection_b` have different shapes.

Comment: @PM2Ring Not if you define them in that way. What I'm saying is: instead of having `selection_b` depend on the result in `selection_a` requiring a nested selection, just define it with the same shape as `selection_a` and use `&` to "filter". You can always rewrite a nested condition `[a][b][c][d]` into `[a& b' & c' & d']` where the primed versions `b'`, `c'`, `d'` (ecc.) have the same shape as `a`.

Comment: The key is that `arr_1[selection_a]` is a `copy`, not a `view`.  The assignment is modifying a portion of that copy, not a portion of the original.  `numpy` is not parsing the 2 criteria together.  Python is performing two separate indexing operations.

Comment: Another question involving this double indexing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323524/whats-the-difference-when-indexing-a-numpy-array-between-using-an-integer-and-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single use of `[...]` operators creates a selection in an array, from which you can read and to which you can write. A second use of `[...]` will read values with no problem. But as far as writing is concerned, the second access will be to a temporary array created to match the selection rules (i.e. a temporary of shape `(2,)` that is a copy of the original data) in your situation.

Edit: Boolean indexing is part of so-called "Advanced Indexing". Keeping the indexing to simple slices avoids these copy issues.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to **Pierre de Buyl** solution, If you want to get your desired result of changing `arr_1` array. You can use `np.where` as follows:

```
arr_1[selection_a] = np.where(arr_2[selection_a]>5,arr_2[selection_a],arr_1[selection_a])

arr_1
```

Which gives

```
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  6, -1,  8, -1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with `=` in python being interpreted as `.__setitem__()`, which can pick the memory addresses from the assigned variable.  However, it doesn't do this recursively, so while

```
a[boolean_mask] = 0
```

works, as the indexing points to the memory in `a`,

```
a[mask1][mask2] = 0
```

does not, as the indexing points to the memory in `a[mask1]`, which is a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the conditions of `selection_a` and `selection_b` do not depend on each other, you could just create a combined mask

```
selection_c = (np.arange(10) % 2 == 0) & (arr_2 >  5)
```

and use it like

```
arr_1[selection_c] = 5
```